# How to prevent text overflow when using Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm working on set of checkboxes, displayed using Angular UI Bootstraps button set.

What I've tried:

1. I've tried using the 'white-space' css declaration, but it did not help.
2. I've also tried changing the individual buttons out from `<label>` to both `<div>` & `<a>`

Neither of these solved the issue of overflowing text.

How can I easily prevent the text from overflowing here?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/03ujphxg/

If you shrink the width of the right-handed column, while it may not be easy to see due to the placement of the resulting display, you'll see the text overflow.

Notes: I can not (prefer not to) set specific width or heights on the button elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to be more specific with your CSS rule to override .btn's white-space property.

```
label.btn {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Or you could add another container inside your buttons and give that the white-space property.

```
<label class="btn btn-default">
    <span style="white-space: normal">
        <input type="checkbox">
        Connections / Hoses Leaking or Cracked Connections / Hoses Leaking or Cracked
    </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Adding the  `<span>` element was a simple solve.  Thanks, Eightdotthree.